By using ts-morph, how to find all exported React components and wrap with ErrorBoundary HOC for future easier debugging?
For debugging issue, currently I've got to implement some code to wrap all the (named & default) exported React components (including React components inside namespace) with ErrorBoundary HOC to find out where the issue arose from.
React components that might look something like this should be wrapped:

ex.1

export const BaseButton01 = React.memo(
    React.forwardRef<Types.RefElement, Types.Props>((props, ref) => {
        return <Styles.BaseButton01 ref={ref} {...props} />;
    })
);
BaseButton01.displayName = "BaseButton01";


ex.2

export const SomeJsx = <button>Some Button</button>

Maybe ErrorBoundary class component and HOC might look something like:
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as Types from "./types";
export { Types as ErrorBoundary02Types };

export class ErrorBoundary02 extends Component<Types.Props, Types.State> {
  state: Types.State = {
    hasError: false,
    error: null,
    errorInfo: null
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error): Types.State {
    return { hasError: true, error, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo) {
    console.error(
      `Error caught in ${this.props.componentName}:`,
      error,
      errorInfo
    );
    this.setState({ errorInfo });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Something went wrong in {this.props.componentName}.</h2>
          <details style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>
            {this.state.error && this.state.error.toString()}
            <br />
            {this.state.errorInfo?.componentStack}
          </details>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export function withErrorBoundary<T extends object>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>
) {
  return class extends Component<T> {
    render() {
      return (
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props as T} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      );
    }
  };
}

Please help!! I've been working with this for a week already!!
